# How can I auto assign a phone number to another field in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I have a business card reader app on my iPhone which assign the landline phone number from the business card to the " principal" phone number field in Outlook. I would like to copy this number to the field "office number".

I would like to have some way for Outlook to iterate through all contacts of the default contact folder; for each contact, test if the field phone number "principal" is different than `NULL` then copy the existing number to the phone number field "office".

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in your software, or more specifically a design flaw. Your software, IMO should have been smart enough to ask for the input and not require this on your part.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using [VBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications) and a little programming.

Some suggested reading to get you started towards your goal:

- [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx)
- [Programmatically Updating Company Names in Outlook 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd673657(v=office.12).aspx)

If along the way you run into specific programming problems, I'd suggest searching and posting questions on [StackOverflow.com](http://www.StackOverflow.com).